# Is there a way to send event data from web page to Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, streaming

Is there a way to send event data directly from web page (browser) to Kafka, and if there are multiple ways then what is the best way? any guidance on this would be appreciated.

Comment: You could, but that would mean that anyone could send any data to Kafka directly, since the web page runs in the user machine. You probably don't want that. Usually what you want is an endpoint that gets called from the frontend that produces to Kafka.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a generic question, but there are multiple ways to do this and it all depends on what tech stack you are adopting into your eco system. Also each tech stack will be having it's own pros and cons.

- Spring Boot + MVC Stack (Ref : https://spring.io/projects/spring-kafka)
- Atomic KAFKA (Ref : https://javascript.plainenglish.io/how-to-integrate-apache-kafka-into-your-web-app-using-atomickafka-2eb79b20eaae)
- Java Script ( Ref : https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-rest)
- Node JS (Ref : https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-rest-node)